# To initialize a 2D array a nested loop is not necessary.

Tags: java, arrays

To initialize a 2D array a nested loop is not necessary? A nested for loop in an array is needed to  to access all elements in the two-dimensional array?

Comment: These are more statements than questions. What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not necessary:

```
int[][] int2dArray = new int[][] {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}};
String[][] string2dArray = new String[][]{{"00", "01"}, {"10", "11"}};
BigInteger[][] bigint2dArray = new BigInteger[][] {
    { new BigInteger("1") },
    { new BigInteger("2"), new BigInteger("3") }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really, you can simulate increasing of two indexes in a single loop.
m X n - size of your array

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < m*n; ++k) {
//Access your array
if (i < m)
++i;
else {
i = 0;
++j;
}
}
```

Something like this should work.
The condition inside the loop can also look like

```
i < m-1 && j < n-1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to access all of the elements in a two-dimensional array, that is, to traverse the array, using nested for loops is one way of accomplishing this task.

For example, imagine that you initialized a two dimensional array like so:

```
int[][] array2D = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

for (int i = 0; i < array2D.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < array2D[i].length; j++) {

        //Do something with each element in the two-dimensional array.
        //For example:
        System.out.println(array2D[i][j]);

    }

}
```

The code segment above would loop through each element in the two-dimensional array, printing each one out. At each iteration of the inner for loop, array2D[i][j] represents the current element in the two-dimensional array.